# How to describe the region $0<x^3<y<\sqrt{x}<1$ using the coordinates$g(u,v)=(\frac{u}{v},v)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, coordinate-systems

I need to put the region $0<x^3<y<\sqrt{x}<1$ in terms of u,v using the change of coordinates $g(u,v)=(\frac{u}{v},v)$ but I don't know how to do this. If I just do the change , I get $u\in (0,v)$ and $v\in \left(\frac{u^3}{v^3},\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}\right)$, and I don't think this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of EMS.

---

Unsure if this is what you want.  Please advise if you are looking for a different format.

$$v \in (0,1).\tag1 $$

$u^3 < v \implies u < v^{1/3}.$ 
Also, $v < u^{1/2} \implies v^2 < u.$

Therefore, $v^2 < u < v^{1/3}.$ 
Therefore,

$$u \in \left(v^2, v^{1/3}\right).\tag2 $$

---

Alternatively,

$$u \in (0,1), ~~v \in \left(u^3, \sqrt{u}\right).$$

---

Another alternative (I am just guessing here).

Let $r$ denote $\dfrac{u}{v}.$

Then you have the change of coordinates: 
$g(u,v) = \left(\dfrac{u}{v},v\right) = (r,v).$

Using (2) above, you have that

$v^2 < u < v^{1/3} \implies v < r < v^{-2/3}.$

So, you have coordinates $(r,v)$ where 
$v \in (0,1)$ and $r \in \left(v, v^{-2/3}\right).$

---

---

---

$\underline{\textbf{Addendum}}$
Responding to the comment/question of EMS.

> could you give me a hint with making an alternative such as the one made in the first alternative?

Let $r$ denote $\dfrac{u}{v}.$

Then you have the change of coordinates: 
$g(u,v) = \left(\dfrac{u}{v},v\right) = (r,v).$

At the end of my original answer, the result was

$$v \in (0,1) ~~~~\text{and}~~~~ r \in \left(v, v^{-2/3}\right). \tag3 $$

I am interpreting your request to be that instead, you want to provide a lower and upper bound for $(r)$, and then provide a lower and upper bound for $(v)$, in terms of $(r)$.

**Edit**
If this is not what you are asking for, then please leave another comment question, and I will add an Addendum-2 to my answer.

---

Using (3) above as a starting point, the goal is to
fill in the following blanks:

$$\text{Allowable range for} ~(r)~ \text{is} ~? \tag4 $$

$$\text{Given a specific value for} ~(r),~ \text{the allowable range for} ~(v)~ \text{is} ~? \tag5 $$

First, preliminary results are needed.

---

$\underline{\text{Preliminary results:}}$

**Lemma 1** 
$\displaystyle 0 < a < 1 \implies 1 < a^{-(2/3)}.$ 
**Proof**
$\displaystyle 0 < a < 1 \implies 0 < a^{1/3} < 1 \implies 0 < \left[a^{1/3}\right]^2 = a^{2/3} < 1 \implies $ 
$\displaystyle 1 < \frac{1}{a^{2/3}} = a^{-(2/3)}.$

**Lemma 2** 
$\displaystyle 1 < a \implies 0 < a^{-(3/2)} < 1.$ 
**Proof**
$\displaystyle 1 < a \implies 1 < a^{1/2} \implies 1 < \left[a^{1/2}\right]^3 = a^{3/2} \implies $ 
$\displaystyle 1 > \frac{1}{a^{3/2}} = a^{-(3/2)}.$ 
Further, 
$\displaystyle 1 < a \implies 0 < a \implies 0 < a^{1/2} \implies $ 
$\displaystyle 0 < \left[a^{1/2}\right]^3 = a^{3/2} \implies 0 < \frac{1}{a^{3/2}} = a^{-(3/2)}.$ 
Therefore, 
$\displaystyle 1 < a \implies 1 > a^{-(3/2)} ~~~~$
and
$~~~~\displaystyle 0 < a^{-(3/2)}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Completion of the Addendum}}$ 
Before attacking (4) and (5) above, the contraints to be satisfied must be listed:

- Constraint **C-1** $~: ~0 < v < 1.$
- Constraint **C-2** $~: ~v < r.$
- Constraint **C-3** $~: \displaystyle ~r < v^{-(2/3)}.$

Now, (4) above will be attacked by the following claim:
**Claim**
For all $(r)$ such that $0 < r$, 
there exists a $(v)$ such that each of **C-1**, **C-2**, and **C-3** are satisfied.

Assuming that the claim is proven, this will resolve (4) above, since it will be established that the allowable range for $(r)$ is any $(r)$ such that $0 < r.$

**Proof of Claim**
To prove this claim, each of the following cases must be examined separately:

- Case 1: $0 < r \leq 1.$
- Case 2: $1 < r.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~0 < r \leq 1}$

Choose $~\displaystyle v = \frac{r}{2} \implies 0 < v < r \leq 1.$ 
Therefore, **C-1** and **C-2** are both satisfied. 
Further, by Lemma 1, since $0 < v < 1, ~
r \leq 1 < v^{-(2/3)}.$ 
Therefore, **C-3** is also satisfied.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~1 < r}$

By Lemma 2, $~0 < r^{-(3/2)} < 1.$ 
Choose $~\displaystyle v = \frac{r^{-(3/2)}}{2} \implies 0 < v < 1 < r.$ 
Therefore, Therefore, **C-1** and **C-2** are both satisfied. 
Further, 
since $~\displaystyle 0 < v < r^{(-3/2)} < 1,$ 
$\displaystyle v^{-1} = \frac{1}{v} > \frac{1}{r^{(-3/2)}} = r^{(3/2)} > 1 \implies $ 
$~\displaystyle v^{-(2/3)} = \left[v^{(-1)}\right]^{(2/3)} > \left[r^{(3/2)}\right]^{(2/3)} = r.$ 
Therefore, **C-3** is also satisfied.

---

Now, with (4) above resolved, (5) will be attacked.  That is, a lower and upper bound for $(v)$, in terms of $(r)$ will be established.  To do this, two cases must be considered:

- Case 1: $0 < r \leq 1.$
- Case 2: $1 < r.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~0 < r \leq 1}$ 
From **C-1** and **C-2** above, you must have that 
$0 < v < r \leq 1.$ 
Then, by Lemma 1,
$~\displaystyle r \leq 1 < v^{-(2/3)} \implies $ 
**C-3** is automatically satisfied.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~1 < r}$ 
From **C-1** and **C-2** above, you must have that 
$0 < v < 1 < r.$

However, by Lemma 2, $~\displaystyle 0 < r^{-(3/2)} < 1.$ 
Therefore, if 
$~\displaystyle r^{-(3/2)} \leq v < 1$, 
then 
$\displaystyle 1 < v^{-1} = \frac{1}{v} \leq \frac{1}{r^{-(3/2)}} = r^{(3/2)} \implies $ 
$\displaystyle v^{-(2/3)} = \left[v^{-1}\right]^{(2/3)} \leq \left[r^{(3/2)}\right]^{(2/3)} = r \implies $ 
**C-3** is violated.

Alternatively, if 
$~\displaystyle 0 < v < r^{-(3/2)} < 1$, 
then 
$\displaystyle 1 < r^{(3/2)} = \frac{1}{r^{-(3/2)}} < \frac{1}{v} = v^{-1} \implies $ 
$\displaystyle r = \left[r^{(3/2)}\right]^{(2/3)} < \left[v^{-1}\right]^{(2/3)} = v^{-(2/3)} \implies $ 
**C-3** is satisfied.

Therefore, in Case 2, you must have that 
$~\displaystyle 0 < v < r^{-(3/2)}.$

---

$\underline{\text{In Summary}}$

$(r)$ can be any value such that $0 < r.$

When $r \leq 1$, you must have that 
$0 < v < r.$

When $1 > r$, you must have that 
$~\displaystyle 0 < v < r^{-(3/2)}.$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I was looking for something like the third alternative. I need to put that region in terms of the transformation $(\frac{u}{v},v) and I think its the way you did it in the third alternative

Comment: Hello again, could you give me a hint with making an alternative such as the one made in the first alternative

Comment: @EMS See the Addendum that I just added to the end of my answer.